# How to check for a null cookie in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following switch statement is not catching a cookie that does not exist.

```
switch (stateCookie) {
                    case 'Virginia':
                        window.location = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
                        break;
                    case 'North Carolina':
                        window.location = '/Teacher-Login/NC';
                        break;
                    case 'South Carolina':
                        window.location = '/Teacher-Login/SC';
                        break;
                    case null:
                        window.location = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
                        break;
                    case '':
                        window.location = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
                    default:
                        window.location = '/pages/state-login/login.html';
```

Ok, I have tried several things but I am still inexplicably having trouble with this. Here is the code that I have at this moment:

```
$('#welcome select').change(function () {
    var stateSelected = $('option:selected', this).val();
    var stateCookie = getCookie("ia_state");
    if(stateSelected != stateCookie)
    {
        setCookie('ia_state', stateSelected);
        switch (stateCookie) {
            case 'Virginia':
            case null:
            case '':
                window.location = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
                break;
            case 'North Carolina':
                window.location = '/Teacher-Login/NC';
                break;
            case 'South Carolina':
                window.location = '/Teacher-Login/SC';
                break;
            default:
                window.location = '/pages/state-login/login.html';
}
}
});
```

The switch statement is being evaluated but it is always going to the default case. I have yet to figure out how to catch it if the cookie is null/undefined.

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/uwsaf/ ... Is goes for `null` also over `''` and `0` and `false` . Try moving around the sequence of the cases

Comment: `var stateCookie = $.cookie("ia_state") || '';` Use jQuery cookie getter and grant's you will get a cookie or empty string.

Comment: You just answered someone's question that it was undefined. That has to do with the getCookie function. Check that function, as it probably returns the cookie if found and just drops out without returning anything if nothing found leaving you undefined. You could just add "case undefined:" to the switch too (see updated post).

Comment: I receive this error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'

Comment: We should see your getCookie/setCookie functions to know what they're doing. I don't think they are standard functions.

Comment: craniumonempty, your suggestion for setting a "case undefined:" worked perfectly. And yes, you are also correct regarding my getCookie/setCookie functions. I really appreciate the help. Not sure what I should do as far as marking an answer though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Mike Stewart. You are missing a break, so if it's returning as '', then it will go on to the default statement. If you are still getting odd results after changing that, then it's possible the problem is somewhere else.

```
var loc = '';
switch (stateCookie) {
    case 'Virginia':
    case null:
    case '':
    case undefined:
        loc = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
        break;
    case 'North Carolina':
        loc = '/Teacher-Login/NC';
        break;
    case 'South Carolina':
        loc = '/Teacher-Login/SC';
        break;
    default:
        loc = '/pages/state-login/login.html';
        break;
};
window.location = loc;
```

EDIT: added undefined case

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a break:

```
                ...
                case '':
                    window.location = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
                    break;
                default:
                    window.location = '/pages/state-login/login.html';
                    break;
```

mdn has item function:

```
function hasItem(sKey) { 
    return (new RegExp("(?:^|;\\s*)" + escape(sKey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
if( $.cookie('cookiename') == null ) {
   /// is null
}
```

Comment: I get a script error when trying this code using the name of my cookie: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'cookie'

Answer (score 0):

Validate your cookie before it enters in the switch, like:

```
stateCookie = (typeof stateCookie != 'string')?'':stateCookie;
```

Then the switch.

So, remove the case null from your switch.

```
case '':
    window.location = '/Teacher-Login/VA';
```

Comment: if the cookie is a string, you are emptying it out. Not sure if you caught that.

Comment: Thanks, I have made an mistake. It's when not a string, return a empty string and when it is, return the string. So for null returns or any other invalid, will become empty string.

Comment: This seems like it should work but when I tried it the value of stateCookie remained undefined after this line executed.

Comment: Please create an example code that reproduce your bug in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ I think that the problem maybe something else. Because if it was undefined, the typeof will return 'undefined' then will apply the empty string to it.